# How to perform soft delete using JPA @Query and @Param Annotations?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, spring-data-jpa, sql-update

I am trying to update the existing rows in database table using JPA @Query Annotation. I want to perform Soft delete by updating the Deleted_Flag to YES from NO.

Here is my Code snippet:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE TBL_NAME SET DELETE_FLAG = 'YES' WHERE DELETE_FLAG = 'NO' 
AND FILE_NM = :FILE_NM")
public void softDelete(@Param("FILE_NM") String fileName)
{
}
```

I am not getting any error, but data is not being updated in database.

Actual result must be like all the existing rows must be updated with DELETE_FLAG to YES.

Comment: FYI The JPA API does not have an `@Query` annotation. That is SPRING. Best to know what you are using ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you invoke the repository method with an active transaction.

Actually, in my last project I use the following idiom for updating a flag :

Entity is annotated with Hibernetish:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="myTable")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = 0")
@Cacheable
public class MyTable {}
```

Actual update comes with a trivial find method:

```
   @Transactional
    public void deleteById(@NonNull final Long themeId) {
        themeRepository.findById(themeId).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(THEME_NOT_FOUND + themeId))
                .setDeleted(true);
    }
```